# TCP Reset After TCP Zero Window

Tags: c, sockets, printing, tcp

For many years our custom software is printing on different printers using the Printer Command Language (PCL).

Now we have a new new, leightweight printer which we are trying to support. A simple print is working flawlessly. However, if the print job grows in size we encounter an interuption of the print job.

Environment:

- no active network hardware (like packet-inspecting firewall) in between.
- the workstation (this is where our software runs) is on Linux kernel version 3.0.101. Here the TCP reset decribed below is happening.

Using Wireshark we found out the following:

- We see the TCP receive window size of the printer going to zero every 2-3 seconds. This is an indicator that the printer hardware is too slow to process the incoming data in real time.
- This zero window time out usually takes about 1-2 seconds.
- After the printer sends the workstation the "zero window" acknowledge packet the workstation tries to keep up the connection to the printer by sending a TCP keep alive packet on a regular basis.
- The printer is answering this keep alive packet.
- In the moment the printer is ready to process data again it sends an "TCP Window Update" packet to the workstation. This packet contains the new receive window size of the printer. As soon as the workstation receives this packet it starts sending out data to the printer again.

Here is a trace snippet of the communication just explained:
[image]

My understanding of the "TCP zero window" mechanism is that stopping and restarting of the communication can go for ever as long as the printer is answering the keepalive packets of the workstation.

In our case however, the communication is interupted after a while:
[image]

After a while (usually after 1-3 minutes) *the workstation* is not sending a new keepalive anymore but is resetting the communication. For us this is not explainable since all the previous keep alive packets where acknowledged by the printer straight away.

I also had no success trying to replicate the scenario. I wrote a simple TCP client and server. To force the TCP zero window to occur the TCP server was sleeping for a certain time, than receiving data continues. 
However, no matter how long the server did wait (sleep) or interupted the transfer, I could never get either of the two to reset the communication. Instead, the TCP keepalive/ acknowledge algorithm described above was running in the idle times keeping the connection alive.

Do you have any ideas what makes our workstation send this reset in the middle of a valid TCP connection?

Comment: We just encountered this same exact issue but with an apache server sending MPEG data to a .NET client. The client responds with a ZeroWindow after some time while it's processing and occupied with audio playback. It always answers keep-alives but after a while the server decides to just terminate the connection with a RST.
Did you find a valid solution or explanation for this behavior?